Handling platform exceptions in MAUI
The question is whether platform exceptions (Android and iOS) are automatically converted to c# exceptions. In particular, for iOS I have a method doSomething(some params, NSError** error). Does MAUI automatically checks that the error when calling doSomething and throws exception? For Android my method doSomething throws java.lang.RuntimeException, can I catch it as a c# exception?

You can try to add the following code to file App.xaml.cs.
public App()
{
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException+=CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException;
 
}

private void CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException(object sender, System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"UNHANDLED EXCEPTION! Details: {e.Exception.ToString()}");
}

And there are some hot discussions about this, you can check them here: Global exception handling and How Do You Create A Global Error Handling for a MAUI App.
